Issues with Setting Alternate Data Streams (ADS) in VB.NET for a Windows Service
I am developing a Windows Service in VB.NET that copies files and directories from one location to another. To avoid copying the same files multiple times, I am using Alternate Data Streams (ADS) to set a custom attribute "HasBeenCopied" for the files and directories. Below is my code for the service:
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Timers

Public Class FolderCopyService
    Dim WithEvents CockpitTimer As New Timer
    Dim gVersion As String = "V23.00g / 28.02.24"
    Public gServicename As String = "FolderCopyService"
    Public gServicenameKurz As String = "FCS"
    Public strLogEintrag As String = "FCS " & gVersion
    Dim Inipfad As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\cockpit.ini"
    Dim CockpitINI As New INIDatei(Inipfad)
    Dim gTestmodus As String = CockpitINI.WertLesen("Testmodus", gServicename)
    Dim gProtokollModus As String = CockpitINI.WertLesen("ProtokollModus", gServicename)
    Dim gProtokollStufe As Integer
    Dim gProtokollierung As MediProtokoll
    Dim strMessage As String
    Dim quelle As String = "C:\Users\nmo\Desktop\Quelle"
    Dim ziel As String = "C:\Users\nmo\Desktop\Ziel"

    ' Name of the custom attribute (Alternate Data Stream)
    Dim copyFlagName As String = "HasBeenCopied"

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        Dim vProtokolldatei As String
        Dim vProtokollstufe As String

        vProtokollstufe = CockpitINI.WertLesen("ProtokollStufe", gServicename)
        If vProtokollstufe <> "" Then
            gProtokollStufe = CInt(vProtokollstufe)
        Else
            gProtokollStufe = 1
        End If

        gProtokollierung = New MediProtokoll(gServicename, gServicenameKurz & " " & gVersion, gTestmodus, gProtokollModus, gProtokollStufe)
        vProtokolldatei = gProtokollierung.Anlegen()
        gProtokollierung.Write(strLogEintrag & " started. Logging in " & vProtokolldatei & ", Test mode: " & gTestmodus & ", Log mode: " & gProtokollModus & ", Log level: " & gProtokollStufe, EventLogEntryType.Information)
        strMessage = strLogEintrag & " started..."
        gProtokollierung.Write(strMessage, EventLogEntryType.Information)
        CockpitTimer.Interval = 60000 ' 1 minute
        CockpitTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        strLogEintrag = gServicenameKurz & " " & gVersion & " " & System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name & ": "
        gProtokollierung.WriteT(strLogEintrag & " stopped", EventLogEntryType.Information)
        CockpitTimer.Stop()
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles CockpitTimer.Elapsed
        strLogEintrag = gServicenameKurz & " " & gVersion & " " & System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name & ": "
        CopyDocuments(quelle, ziel)
    End Sub

    ' Method to copy documents and directories
    Private Sub CopyDocuments(ByVal sourceDir As String, ByVal targetDir As String)
        Try
            If Not Directory.Exists(targetDir) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir)
            End If

            For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir)
                Dim targetFile As String = Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file))
                If Not HasFlag(file) Then
                    Try
                        File.Copy(file, targetFile, True)
                        gProtokollierung.WriteT($"Document copied - {file} to {targetFile}", EventLogEntryType.Information)
                        SetFlag(file)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        gProtokollierung.Write($"Error copying {file} to {targetFile}: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error)
                    End Try
                Else
                    gProtokollierung.WriteT($"Copy skipped, flag already present - {targetFile}", EventLogEntryType.Information)
                End If
            Next

            For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir)
                Dim targetSubDir As String = Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(dir))
                CopySubDirectory(dir, targetSubDir)
            Next

            SetFlag(sourceDir)
            gProtokollierung.WriteT($"Directory {sourceDir} successfully copied to {targetDir} and flag set.", EventLogEntryType.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
            gProtokollierung.Write($"Error copying {sourceDir} to {targetDir}: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub CopySubDirectory(ByVal sourceSubDir As String, ByVal targetSubDir As String)
        Try
            If Not Directory.Exists(targetSubDir) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetSubDir)
            End If

            For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourceSubDir)
                Dim targetFile As String = Path.Combine(targetSubDir, Path.GetFileName(file))
                If Not HasFlag(file) Then
                    Try
                        File.Copy(file, targetFile, True)
                        gProtokollierung.WriteT($"Document copied - {file} to {targetFile}", EventLogEntryType.Information)
                        SetFlag(file)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        gProtokollierung.Write($"Error copying {file} to {targetFile}: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error)
                    End Try
                Else
                    gProtokollierung.WriteT($"Copy skipped, flag already present - {targetFile}", EventLogEntryType.Information)
                End If
            Next

            For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sourceSubDir)
                Dim targetSubSubDir As String = Path.Combine(targetSubDir, Path.GetFileName(dir))
                CopySubDirectory(dir, targetSubSubDir)
            Next

            SetFlag(sourceSubDir)
            gProtokollierung.WriteT($"Directory {sourceSubDir} successfully copied to {targetSubDir} and flag set.", EventLogEntryType.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
            gProtokollierung.Write($"Error copying {sourceSubDir} to {targetSubDir}: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' Method to check if the custom attribute is set
    Private Function HasFlag(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(path & ":" & copyFlagName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
                Return fs.Length > 0
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            gProtokollierung.Write($"Error checking flag for {path}: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    ' Method to set a custom attribute
    Private Sub SetFlag(ByVal path As String)
        Try
            Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(path & ":" & copyFlagName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
                Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Flag set")
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            End Using
            gProtokollierung.WriteT($"Flag set for {path}", EventLogEntryType.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
            gProtokollierung.Write($"Error setting flag for {path}: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Problem:
I am encountering the following errors in the log:
Error setting flag for C:\Users\nmo\Desktop\Quelle: The specified path format is not supported.
Error setting flag for C:\Users\nmo\Desktop\Quelle\FolderA\A1\A2\ZAPP.pdf: The specified path format is not supported.
Error setting flag for C:\Users\nmo\Desktop\Quelle\FolderA\A1\A2: The specified path format is not supported.
Error setting flag for C:\Users\nmo\Desktop\Quelle\FolderA\A1: The specified path format is not supported.
Error setting flag for C:\Users\nmo\Desktop\Quelle\FolderA: The specified path format is not supported.

I am trying to use Alternate Data Streams (ADS) to set a custom attribute "HasBeenCopied" on files and directories to prevent copying the same documents multiple times. My goal is to achieve this in a way that I do not need to perform manual cleanup in the target folder later on.
Question:
How can I resolve the issue with setting Alternate Data Streams? Are there any limitations or special considerations I need to be aware of when using ADS? Or is there a mistake in the way I am using Alternate Data Streams in my code?
Thank you in advance for your help!
